# Is it possible to get the address of a macro?

Tags: c

```
#define N 100
```

`&N` not possible. How can I know the address of N? It must have some address.

Comment: No `N` does not have an address, it is simple text substitution. The compiler's pre-processor replaces all occurrences of `N` with `100`.

Comment: you probably want to do a global variable instead.

Comment: @user3779430 A static file scope variable perhaps. There is never a reason ever to use global variables.

Answer (score 5):

> A macro is a fragment of code which has been given a name. Whenever
>   the name is used, it is replaced by the contents of the macro.

So NO `N` is not a variable and you can't get the address of `N`

[MACROS](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Macros.html)

Answer (score 3):

Macros don't have any addresses and that's why they are referred to as constant values.

Answer (score 3):

A macro is simple text substitution. If you write code like

```
int* ptr = &N;
```

it will then be pre-processed into

```
int* ptr = &100;
```

`100` is an *integer literal* and all integer literals are constant rvalues, meaning you can't assign a value to it, nor can you take its address.

The literal `100` is of course stored in memory though - you can't allocate numbers in thin air - but it will most likely be stored as part of the executed program code. In the binary, you'll have some machine code instruction looking like "store 100 in the memory location of the pointer variable" and the `100` is stored in that very machine code instruction. And a part of a machine code instruction isn't addressable.

Answer (score 2):

It is simple text substitution. The compiler's pre-processor replaces all occurrences of `N` with `100`, but, it depends on what `N` is. In your example taking the address of a constant won't compile, but these two other examples *do* work.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define N 100
#define M x
#define L "Hallo world!"

int main()
{
    int x = 42;
    //printf ("Address of 'N' is %p\n", (void*)&N);  // error C2101: '&' on constant
    printf ("Address of 'M' is %p\n", (void*)&M);
    printf ("Address of 'L' is %p\n", (void*)&L);
    return 0;
}
```

Program output:

```
Address of 'M' is 0018FF3C
Address of 'L' is 0040C018
```

**MORE** explanation.

With `#define N 100` you can't get the address of `N` because a numerical constant like that does not have a single memory location. `100` might be assigned to the value of a variable, or indeed the optimising compiler might load `100` directly into a processor register.

In the case of `#define M x` that's a simple substitution so that `M` can be used exactly as `x` can. There is no functional difference between `&x` and `&M` because the two statements are identical after the preprocessor has made the substitution.

In the case of `#define L "Hallo world!"` we have a string literal, which the compiler *does* place in memory. Asking for `&L` is the same as asking for `&"Hallo world!"` and that is what you get.

Comment: could you explain more that why N 100 hasn't  but N "DQEQ" has . ones int and ones string ..

Comment: @BijooSingh added explanation.

Answer (score 1):

`N` is *not* a variable, it *never* has any address. It's just a value to get pasted in when you use patterns like `int val=N;`. Then you can get the address of `val` using `&`.